# Why does ioLoop in tornado seem to add root logger handler?

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I have used python `logging` in my system and worked find.
My log hierarchy is like below.

1. Define log `A` which has handler and formatter.
2. log `A` inherit `A.B`, `A.C`....(child loggers just use handler and formatter of `A`)
3. I don't add root logger handler.

So all logger had worked find, sharing handler of `A`.

And I needed to add `Websocket` procedure, so I choose Tornado.
But after adding `Tornado`, suddenly duplicated log appear.

for example.

```
Time-A : log message  #This is log message I print
INFO:A : log message  #This is duplicated log message
```

In more detail, If i call `ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()`
If I block `ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()`, the issue is not found.

Seems that root logger handler is added by `ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()`.

Why? and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event loops must catch exceptions from their callbacks; Tornado uses logging to tell you that an exception has occurred. If there were no handler configured you'd never see these messages, so the IOLoop creates a handler if necessary when it is started. To prevent this, define a handler for either the root logger or the `tornado` logger before starting the IOLoop.

When the IOLoop creates a handler, it does so for the root logger instead of the `tornado` logger because root handlers are automatically created in other places (i.e. the logging module's top-level functions like logging.error), so there would be double logging if the IOLoop created a `tornado` handler and then some other module called `logging.error` and created a root handler.